# TYPO3 var/log - how to auto remove entries after x days

Tags: typo3

In TYPO3 10 logs are beeing stored, amoung others, in var/log. Files that are stored there are growing over time. Is there a way to keep it clean and keep automatically entries from x last days?

Answer (score 0):

Would be eventually quite a task of an operation. Normaly, log rotating is a job for the OS, so you may use something like logrotate or similar to rotate the logs.

Comment: And it is the job of the devs/integrators to check, *what* needs to be logged. If nobody uses the logs (or a special scope of entries), why should it be logged?
"Configuration of the logging system" (https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/Logging/Configuration/Index.html)